# Add harmonics to Clark and Park

Tags: three-phase, math

I have a problem with adding harmonics to park-clark transformed 3 phase value. Here is transformations I'm using:

```
Vsd= 1, Vsq= 1, x=angle;
sinA = sin(x);
cosA = cos(x);
a= Vsd * cosA - Vsq * sinA;
b= Vsd * cosA + Vsq * sinA;
Va= a;
Vb= -1/2*a + sqrt(3)/2*b;
Vb= -1/2*a - sqrt(3)/2*b;
```

and on the graphs I get following result:
[image]

When I'm trying to add harmonics to sine and cosine, for example 3rd harmonic:

```
sinA = sin(x) + sin(3*x);
cosA = cos(x) + cos(3*x);
```

I'm getting mess instead of M shaped waves on all 3 phases:

[image]

what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: What do you expect to get?  I suggest making the harmonic components lower in amplitude - multiply them by say 0.1 or 0.2 and then look at the result.

Comment: I'm trying to get M shaped wave form on 3 phases, so it should look like MW (0-2PI) on all 3 phases

Answer (score 1):

cosB = cos(x-π) + cos(3*x-π)
[image]
cosA = cos(x) + cos(3*x)

ref http://www.falstad.com/fourier/

Comment: What is π ? is it PI or Period ? In both case it doesn't solve the problem...

Comment: Pi solves it, see the "M"

Comment: not in my case, try to apply it to sinA = sin(x) + sin(3*x);
cosA = cos(x) + cos(3*x); and then use inverse Park and Clark transform... you will get the same mess